# Compare two cell arrays for identical rows - MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, compare, cells, cell-array

I have a cell string matrix with `40,000` lines and one with `400`. I need to find those rows (lines) in the `first` matrix that fit the `second`. Please note that there could be many repetitions.

It looks:
`40,000` lines like

```
Anna Frank  
Anna George  
Jane Peter  
Anna George  
Jane Peter    
etc.
```

here I need to find the fit to

```
Anna George  
Jane Peter
```

The only way I found that far were two `for` functions and an `if` in between. But it is quite slow:

```
for i=2:size(bigTable,1)
    for j = 1: size(smallTable,1)
        if sum(ismember(bigTable(i,1:2),smallTable(j,1:2))) == 2
            Total_R(size(Total_R,1)+1,1)= i;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you considered concatenating the first and last name? That way a single ismember should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming your input is setup like this -

```
bigTable = 
    'Anna'    'Frank' 
    'Anna'    'George'
    'Jane'    'Peter' 
    'Anna'    'George'
    'Jane'    'Peter' 
smallTable = 
    'Anna'    'George'
    'Jane'    'Peter'
```

To solve your case, two approaches can be suggested here.

**Approach #1**

`ismember` based approach -

```
Total_R = find(sum(ismember(bigTable,smallTable,'rows'),2)==2)
```

**Approach #2**

```
%// Assign unique labels to each cell for both small and big cell arrays, so that
%// later on you would be dealing with numeric arrays only and 
%// do not have to mess with cell arrays that were slowing you down
[unqbig,matches1,idx] = unique([bigTable(:) ; smallTable(:)])
big_labels = reshape(idx(1:numel(bigTable)),size(bigTable))
small_labels = reshape(idx(numel(bigTable)+1:end),size(smallTable))

%// Detect which rows from small_labels exactly match with those from big_labels
Total_R  = find(ismember(big_labels,small_labels,'rows'))
```

Or replace that `ismember` from the last line with a `bsxfun` based implementation -

```
Total_R = find(any(all(bsxfun(@eq,big_labels,permute(small_labels,[3 2 1])),2),3))
```

---

Output from these approaches for the assumed input case -

```
Total_R =
     2
     3
     4
     5
```

Comment: Note: For 2010 or recent versions of MATLAB, you can skip certain outputs, so you can do this instead - `[~,~,idx] = unique([bigTable(:) ; smallTable(:)])`.